# Set contentInset in RecyclerView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a `RecyclerView` like a `UICollectionView` in iOS.
I want to set a `contentInset` at the bottom of the recycler view but I can't find an option to do it.

Is there something similar for Android?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Solution is simple:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:paddingBottom="30dp"
   android:clipToPadding="false"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: This. Simplest solution by far.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own ItemDecoration and set there a offset for the first item and also margins between the items.

Here is my code for my horizontal scrolling recyclerview.

```
public class HorizontalContentItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
  private int startOffset = 10;
  private int itemOffset = 10;

  public HorizontalContentItemDecoration(int startOffset, int itemOffset) {
    this.startOffset = startOffset;
    this.itemOffset = itemOffset;
  }

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                             RecyclerView.State state) {

    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

    if (position == 0) {
      outRect.set(startOffset, 0, itemOffset, 0);
    } else {
      outRect.set(0, 0, itemOffset, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a wrapper adapter to achieve this, which isolates the code nicely. But, I would like a better solution..

```
public class HeaderSpaceWrapperAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0x4711;
    private int mSpace;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;


    public HeaderSpaceWrapperAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, int space) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mSpace = space;

        mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            return new ViewHolder(new Spacer(parent.getContext(), mSpace));
        }

        return mAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position > 0) {
            mAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1 + mAdapter.getItemCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? TYPE_HEADER : mAdapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);
    }

    private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
mWrapperAdapter = new HeaderSpaceWrapperAdapter(mAdapter, 100);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWrapperAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this adding a custom RecyclerView Cell that adds an offset at the end of the view with a clear background color.

Comment: It works... but it seems wrong... I've gone for the same seeing as there aren't any other suggestions. There must be a better solution though!

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be an enhancement to @Phin answer

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    .... 
    Your other code
    ....
    // Check if it is the last item and the list is not empty.
            if(i == arraylist.size()-1) {
                // If so, add some margin to the element
                itemHolder.setBottomMargin(R.dimen.quick_controls_height); // some dimension (or set a fixed amount of pixels
            } else {
                itemHolder.setBottomMargin(R.dimen.zero_margin); //Set zero margin as the views will be reused.
            }

}
```

**dimens.xml :**

```
<dimen name="quick_controls_height">34.1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="zero_margin">0dp</dimen>
```